# Is there a way to programmatically get limitations of a particular feature in Metal?

Tags: metal

I see that a combination of Apple GPU HW and iOS/MacOS version determines a feature set. I can query which feature set my MTLDevice supports using below swift snippet.

```
device.supportsFeatureSet(MTLFeatureSet.osx_GPUFamily1_v1)
```

I still need to refer the table in the below link to get the individual feature limitations.

[Metal Feature Set](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Miscellaneous/Conceptual/MetalProgrammingGuide/MetalFeatureSetTables/MetalFeatureSetTables.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014221-CH13-SW1)

Is there a way to know this programmatically? For example, know how many colorAttachments are supported per renderPass?

Comment: I am hunting for an answer to the same question but unfortunately there is now way right now to get the limitations of the device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no API to query the hardware and software limits of a given device.